# select 5 lastest data by date including data that does not exist

Tags: php, sql, mysql

i want to select 5 lastest data by date (month) including data that does not exist in codeigniter

heres salesdata table (every date fixed by 1)

| id | date | stock | sold |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a1 | 01-01-2024 | 2 | 28 |
| a1 | 01-08-2024 | 12 | 100 |
| a1 | 01-04-2024 | 12 | 28 |
| a3 | 01-01-2024 | 12 | 28 |
| a1 | 01-02-2024 | 9 | 28 |
| a2 | 01-01-2024 | 10 | 28 |
| a1 | 01-03-2024 | 89 | 19 |
| a1 | 01-10-2024 | 12 | 67 |
| a1 | 01-06-2024 | 12 | 28 |

this is what i want on viewwhich.php
the "does not exist" data value are 0

| id | date | stock | sold |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a1 | 01-06-2024 | 12 | 28 |
| a1 | 01-07-2024 | 0 | 0 |
| a1 | 01-08-2024 | 12 | 100 |
| a1 | 01-09-2024 | 0 | 0 |
| a1 | 01-10-2024 | 12 | 67 |
|  | sum | 36 | 195 |

i think it needs some javascript but idk

for now i only can select data that existed

my salescontroller.php

```
$whichid = "a1";

$data [
     'selectwhich1' => $this->modelsales->resultWhich1($whichid)->row(),
     'selectwhich2' => $this->modelsales->resultWhich2($whichid)->row(),
     'selectwhich3' => $this->modelsales->resultWhich3($whichid)->row(),
     'selectwhich4' => $this->modelsales->resultWhich4($whichid)->row(),
     'selectwhich5' => $this->modelsales->resultWhich5($whichid)->row(),
];

$this->load->view('viewwhich',$data);
```

and resultWhich1 code on modelsales.php

```
public function resultWhich1($data){
            return $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM (select * FROM salesdata ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 5) AS x WHERE id = '$data' ORDER BY date ASC LIMIT 1");
        }
public function resultWhich2($data){
            return $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM (select * FROM salesdata ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 4) AS x WHERE id = '$data' ORDER BY date ASC LIMIT 1");
        }
```

etc.

i separated them so i can sum all the resultWhich1-5

thanks

===

of course my viewwhich.php code will be

```
...
<tr>
<td><?= $selectwhich1['id'] ?></td>
<td><?= $selectwhich1['date'] ?></td>
<td><?= $selectwhich1['stock'] ?></td>
<td><?= $selectwhich1['sold'] ?></td>
</tr>
...
```

===

in my head i need to select the latest data

```
select date from salesdata where id = $data order by date desc 1
```

the result should be $lastdate = 2024-10-01

then find the last 5 months base that data like

```
$month1 = date($lastdate,strtotime("-4 months");
$month2 = date($lastdate,strtotime("-3 months");
$month3 = date($lastdate,strtotime("-2 months");
$month4 = date($lastdate,strtotime("-1 month");
```

then check again to database if there data with id and date

```
if (select * from sales data where id = $data and date = $month1){
    $idmonth1 = select id from sales data where id = $data and date = $month1;
    $datemonth1 = select date from sales data where id = $data and date = $month1;
    $stockmonth1 = select stock from sales data where id = $data and date = $month1;
    $soldmonth1 = select sold from sales data where id = $data and date = $month1;
} or {
    $idmonth1 = $data;
    $datemonth1 = $month1;
    $stockmonth1 = 0;
    $soldmonth1 = 0;
}
```

does that make sense

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: im using xampp mysql

Comment: How do you want to break ties? Say you had multiple id's with activity on 2024-01-10?

Comment: its a monthly data btw im using ddmmyyyy format

Answer (score 1):

I don't know CodeIgniter but I do know mysql.

That being said, why wouldnt you use a query like this?

`` "SELECT * FROM `salesdata` WHERE `id` = '$id' ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 5" ``

As far as i can tell it should be like this in CodeIgniter

```
$id   = "a1";
$data = [];
foreach($this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `salesdata` WHERE `id` = '$id' ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT 5")->result_array() as $k => $val){
  $data['selectwhich'.($k+1)] = $val;
}
```

Now your `$data` array should have all of the records in the correct order limited to the latest 5.

But like I said, I've never used CodeIgniter so maybe someone else have a better solution.

Comment: i... think at first i was just need like the 5th last data from latest date then i kinda lazy to create loop and lolol btw thanku

Answer (score 1):

You could do it on the MySQL side with a [recursive CTE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html#common-table-expressions-recursive-date-series) to get the list of relevant dates for the given id:

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE cte (`id`, `date`, `last_date`) AS (
    SELECT `id`, MAX(`date`) - INTERVAL 4 MONTH, MAX(`date`)
    FROM salesdata
    WHERE `id` = 'a1'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT `id`, `date` + INTERVAL 1 MONTH, `last_date`
    FROM cte
    WHERE `date` < `last_date`
)
SELECT cte.id, cte.date, IFNULL(sd.stock, 0) AS stock, IFNULL(sd.sold, 0) AS sold
FROM cte
LEFT JOIN salesdata sd
    ON cte.date = sd.date
    AND cte.id = sd.id;
```

Output:

| id | date | stock | sold |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a1 | 2024-06-01 | 12 | 28 |
| a1 | 2024-07-01 | 0 | 0 |
| a1 | 2024-08-01 | 12 | 100 |
| a1 | 2024-09-01 | 0 | 0 |
| a1 | 2024-10-01 | 12 | 67 |

Here's a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/8HBFvaeU).

This assumes that dates are stored correctly as the [DATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html) datatype (yyyy-mm-dd) and there is only one row per id per month.

P.S. When passing values into your queries you should use [Query Bindings](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/queries.html#query-bindings) or [Named Bindings](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/queries.html#named-bindings) instead of just concatenating strings.

Comment: and how to sum the records?

Comment: You could add [`GROUP BY ... WITH ROLLUP`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html) or sum them in the view.

Comment: Ive never used the "WITH RECURSIVE" directive in mysql... but i would imagine that would hit the server pretty hard if the query is supposed to pull 100k+ records.

Have you ever seen a performance hit from using that approach?

Comment: @dvicemuse The [recursive CTE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html#common-table-expressions-recursive-date-series) is only returning 5 rows, so it is very lightweight. As with most queries, you can easily test with `EXPLAIN` and/or `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` to see what is going on. By default, [`cte_max_recursion_depth`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_cte_max_recursion_depth) is set to 1000.

Comment: nice! I can think of a ton of use cases for that... thx explanation.